# get Liferay user information with primefaces

Tags: primefaces, liferay

I develop a primefaces portlet in Liferay 6.1
Is it possible to get user information in the portlet and if yes how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do in a JSF based portlet, in your case using Primefaces as the JSF implementation, by using the [Liferay Faces library](http://www.liferay.com/community/liferay-projects/liferay-faces/overview): [LiferayFacesContext.getInstance().getUser()](http://www.portletfaces.org/doc/liferayfaces/6.0.0.0/javadoc/org/portletfaces/liferay/faces/context/LiferayFacesContext.html) should give you the Liferay user object for the currently logged in user.